# Displaying multiple contents in android listview from sql server

Tags: android, sql, database, listview, display

Hi guys I tried to insert values of two columns from SQL server table. Initially i tried to display only one content from the server in a listview and it worked fine. But when i try to display two data in two different textviews, my Application crashes and stops.

Here are the complete xml layout code

activity_starter.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.redcabins.Starters">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_starters1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select Food"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_starters2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Selected Food"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_starters1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_starters_quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Quantity"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_starters2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_starters3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_starters_quantity"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_starters_add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_starters3"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/starter_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_starters_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

starterlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_starterlist1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_starterlist2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Following are the java class files

```
DBConnection.java

package com.example.lenovo.redcabins;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Lenovo on 5/1/2017.
 */

public class DBConnection {
Context c;

String un = "sa";
String password = "sa123";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    //String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.xxx.xxx:49170/RedCabins;user=" + un + ";password=" + password);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(c,"Error with SQL Connection"+se,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(c,"Error with SQL Connection"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(c,"Error with SQL Connection"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return conn;
}

}

Starters.java

package com.example.lenovo.redcabins;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Starters extends AppCompatActivity {

DBConnection conclass;
ListView list;
ArrayList<String> itemname1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> price1=new ArrayList<String>();
//ArrayList<Byte> imgid1=new ArrayList<Byte>();

String[] itemname;
String[] price;
///Byte[] imgid;

/*String[] itemname ={

        "Chicken Wings",
        "Chicken Stripes",
        "Potato Wedges",
        "Vegetable Salad",
        "Pork Belly",
        "Golden Roasted Pork",
        "Garlic Bread",
        "Cheesy Garlic Bread"
};*/

/*Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,
        R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,
        R.drawable.pic6,
        R.drawable.pic7,
        R.drawable.pic8,
};*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starters);

    conclass=new DBConnection();
    displaystarterTitle();
    displaystarterPrice();
    //displaystarterImage();
    itemname = (String[]) itemname1.toArray(new String[itemname1.size()]);
    price=(String[])price1.toArray(new String[price1.size()]);
    //imgid=(Byte[])imgid1.toArray(new Byte[imgid1.size()]);

    StarterList adapter=new StarterList(this, itemname,  price);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.starter_list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}

public void displaystarterTitle()
{
    try {

        Connection conn=conclass.CONN();
        if(conn==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error with SQL Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String Starterquery="select * from MenuCard where Mid like 'S%' and MAvailability=1" ;
            Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(Starterquery);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                itemname1.add(rs.getString("MName"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sql connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some other error with the connection"+ex,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void displaystarterPrice()
{
    try {

        Connection conn=conclass.CONN();
        if(conn==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error with SQL Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String Starterquery="select * from MenuCard where Mid like 'S%' and MAvailability=1" ;
            Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(Starterquery);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                itemname1.add(rs.getString("MPrice"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sql connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some other error with the connection"+ex,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/*public void displaystarterImage()
{
    try {

        Connection conn=conclass.CONN();
        if(conn==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error with SQL Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String Starterquery="select * from MenuCard where Mid like 'S%' and MAvailability=1" ;
            Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(Starterquery);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                imgid1.add(rs.getByte("MImage"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sql connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some other error with the connection"+ex,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}*/

}

Starterlist.java
package com.example.lenovo.redcabins;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StarterList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final String[] price;
//private final Byte[] imgid;

public StarterList(Activity context, String[] itemname, String[] price) {
    super(context, R.layout.starterlist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.price=price;
    //this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.starterlist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_starterlist1);
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_starterlist);
    TextView pricetxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_starterlist2);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    //imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    //pricetxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    pricetxt.setText("Rs "+price[position]);
    return rowView;

};

}
```

Can someone please tell me whats the possible issue is

Comment: Can you give crash log of your application ?

Comment: kindly attach the code you are using to fetch multiple contents from server

Comment: thnx i fixed it